# Multiple joins on the same table for different users

Tags: mysql, database

I have a card game. 4 players play in each room. I have 2 tables in my database (MySQL) like this:

Table nr 1: "rooms"

```
id: Int
playerid1: Int
playerid2: Int
playerid3: Int
playerid4: Int
```

Table nr 2: "players"

```
id: Int
name: Varchar
picture: varchar
```

What i'm trying to do is to return all rooms in a query and get player pictures at the same time. It's easy to get a single players picture with join but how do I do it for all 4 players at the same time?

The result should be something like this:

```
id = 123
playerid1 = 1
playerid2 = 2
playerid3 = 3
playerid4 = 4
playerpic1 = "one.jpg"
playerpic2 = "two.jpg"
playerpic3 = "three.jpg"
playerpic4 = "four.jpg"
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Consider revising your schema such that players are represented by 4 rows, not 4 columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need 4 joins of the table `rooms` to `players`:

```
select r.id,
  p1.id, p1.picture,
  p2.id, p2.picture,
  p3.id, p3.picture,
  p4.id, p4.picture
from rooms r
inner join players p1 on p1.id = r.playerid1
inner join players p2 on p2.id = r.playerid2
inner join players p3 on p3.id = r.playerid3
inner join players p4 on p4.id = r.playerid4
```

Comment: Amazing. Thanks. I appreciate your help.